# Electron "force reload" and local file in iframe issue

Tags: iframe, electron

Consider an Electron application with a GUI like this:

```
<body>
  <div><!-- anything here --></div>
  <iframe id="frame" src="document.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

The `iframe` element loads a local file from the app's root directory.

When I start the app (`npm start`), everything works fine. But if I use the "Force Reload" option to see the changes I made without restarting the app, I suddenly bump into a cross origin problem.

**The symptoms:**

**1)** The `iframe` is listening for changes in the app's `localStorage`.

```
let frame = document.getElementById("frame");
frame.contentWindow.addEventListener("storage", function(e) {
  // do something
});
```

After "Force Reload", I get the following error: `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "file://" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

**2)** If I try to access the `contentDocument` of the `iframe`, I get `null`.

```
console.log(frame.contentDocument); // -> null
```

The strange thing is, none of these happen when I start the app, only after I reload it.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug in the latest Electron (5.0.7)? I had no problem with older versions, but I don't know if it's an intended change or a bug, or my mistake.